# recognising encodings in emacs

Tags: unicode, encoding, emacs

It is my understanding that txt files do not have encoding information stored so text editors simply make educated guesses about encoding of a given text file and then display the file on screen using that *guessed* encoding. If the editor guessed right you get your text on the screen, if the editor guessed wrong, then you (sometimes) get gibberish. Am I getting this right so far?

Now on to my problem. I have my bank statements in a csv file. When I open it in MS Excel 14 (MS Office 2010), it recognises the encoding and displays the problematic work as "obračun". Great. When I open the file in Emacs 24.3.1, it fails to recognise the correct encoding and displays the problematic word as "obra鑾n". Not so great.

My question is: how do I tell Emacs which encoding the file is in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specify-Coding.html):

> If Emacs recognizes the encoding of a file incorrectly, you can reread
>   the file using the correct coding system with <kbd>C-x RET r</kbd>
>   (`revert-buffer-with-coding-system`). This command prompts for the
>   coding system to use.

Give `utf-16` a try.

Comment: Thanks, that's the command I'm looking for. And, it's not UTF-16 :-/

Comment: So Excel is obviously better at guessing than me ;-)

Comment: @dijxtra What if you try cp-1250 or iso-8859-2 (latin-2)?

Comment: Turns out it's Windows-1250, yes.